# Proof that composition on $Aut(G)$ is associative

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification, group-isomorphism

Would it be correct to prove it the way below? I'm feeling somewhat ambiguous as to the correctness of my proof. I would appreciate your input.

Proof:

We need to prove that for $\phi$, $\psi$, $\rho \in Aut(G)$, $\phi(\psi\rho)=(\phi\psi)\rho$. Suppose $g\in G$, then:

(i) $[(\phi\psi)\rho](g)=\phi[\psi\rho(g)]=\phi[\psi(\rho(g))]=\phi(\psi(g_\rho))=\phi(g_{\rho\psi})=g_{\rho\psi\phi}$.

(ii)$[\phi(\psi\rho)](g)=\phi[(\psi\rho)(g)]=\phi[\psi(\rho(g))]=\phi(\psi(g_\rho))=\phi(g_{\rho\psi})=g_{\rho\psi\phi}$.

Thus $Aut(G)$ is associative.

Comment: I am unfamiliar with the subscript notation, but the approach seems correct and it should follow essentially immediately from the associativity of the group itselp.

Comment: Composing endomorphisms $G\rightarrow G$ is always associative, so there is nothing to prove.

Comment: @charlestoncrabb you don't need associativity of the group, function composition is always associative

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be well known that composition of functions is always associative. If not, here is the proof:

Suppose $f:A\to B$, $g:B\to C$ and $h:C\to D$ are functions. For any $a\in A$
$$
((h\circ g)\circ f)(a)=(h\circ g)(f(a))=h(g(f(a)))
$$
and
$$
(h\circ(g\circ f))(a)=h((g\circ f)(a))=h(g(f(a))).
$$
The two expressions are equal.